# flask, gunicorn (gevent), sqlalchemy (postgresql): too many connections

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I created `Flask` WSGI-application which uses `gunicorn` as WSGI-server, for DB it uses `PostgreSQL` through `Flask SQLAlchemy` extension. That's all hosted on `Heroku`.

**gunicorn configuration**

- number of workers: 2;
- number of workers connections: 1024;
- number of threads: 1;
- worker class: gevent.

**Heroku PostgreSQL configuration**

- maximum number of connections: 20.

For everything else default configuration is used.

I'm getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: too many connections for role <id>`. Obviously, i'm exceeded allowed number of DB connections.

I tried these things to fix it:

- for SQLAlchemy set `poolclass` to `NullPool`;
- for SQLAlchmey set `pool_recycle` to 2. Number of connections still the same even after more than 2 seconds;
- `session.close()` with `engine.dispose()`;
- number of workers - 2, number of worker connections - 9;
- number of workers - 1, number of worker connections - 18;
- number of workers - 1, number of worker connections - 10, SQLAlchemy `max_overflow = 0`, SQLALchmey `pool_size = 10` (i'm getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30`).

Nothing of this works. I'm still getting this error even with minimum gunicorn configuration (1 worker with 18 connections). I'm really started not to understand what is really going on.

I thought it worked like this: each worker have it's own instance of engine, and each engine have it's own pool size. So, if there is 2 workers with engine default config (pool size is 5), then we have 2 * 5 = 10 maximum connections to DB. But it looks like this is really not like this.

**Questions**

- how to fix this error?
- how `SQLAlchemy` pooling works with `gevent` workers? i.e., how can i count maximum number of DB connections?
- how should I configure it correctly so that it works as expected?

Sorry for too much questions, but it is really frustrating me.

Comment: It sounds like there may be left over connections from previous attempts that have no gone away.  Can you access the database at all (with some other user) and see what is in pg_stat_activity?

Comment: @jjanes After request is ended, 5 minute later, there is many connections with state "
idle in transaction". For example, if i created 10 requests, after 5 minutes these 10 connections will exists with state "idle in transaction". But in these requests i don't do any insert operations, only read.

Comment: regardless of what you did in those transactions, you need to terminate them.  Either through commit, or through closing the connection.

Comment: @jjanes As i wrote in the questions: i tried this `session.close() engine.dispose();` after each request. It didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't matter of the connections are still left over from before you added that code.  Has that code **always** been there?

Comment: you can create class or function to return same connection object until it is not closed by `PostgreSQL` or code like singleton pattern

Comment: @Chandan it is always uses single object that was created at server start up, not created every time at function call

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @Chandan https://github.com/Amaimersion/yandex-disk-telegram-bot/blob/master/src/database/database.py

Comment: i think you need to manually kill the connections from the terminal. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734370/close-an-existing-postgres-connection-using-psycopg2)

Comment: @SiddhantTandon They should be killed automatically, isn't?

Comment: Sorry i said the wrong word you need to manually kill the `process` from the terminal. No matter the state of the connection `active` or `idle`  the process still runs in the background with a specific pid. So you kill it using its pid either using the terminal or from the SQL client.

Comment: @Immersion can you point out where you are getting error in code on which line when running you app, procedure you are using to run and endpoint, also if you can please share stack trace

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same problem while building [this project](https://github.com/meena-erian/pdr) and the only way I was eventually able to address this issue was by [caching `MockConnection`/`database_engine` objects returned by SQLAlchemy's `create_engine`](https://github.com/meena-erian/pdr/blob/4996e152cd49fde18ce831284ce5fefd760e75ae/django_pdr/models.py#L198) method into [a global variable](https://github.com/meena-erian/pdr/blob/4996e152cd49fde18ce831284ce5fefd760e75ae/django_pdr/models.py#L17) and [reusing the same `MockConnection` object if it has already been created](https://github.com/meena-erian/pdr/blob/4996e152cd49fde18ce831284ce5fefd760e75ae/django_pdr/models.py#L178).

Comment: Isn't engine always created once at app initialization stage? If yes, then your code doing same, but in more complicated manner, no? If no, then there will be no any side effects because of manually cached engine?

Comment: Nope. It has nothing to do with app initialization. Every time your app makes a call to the function create_engine, it creates a new engine. And the problem is, that one engine cannot reuse another engine's database connections because each engine has its own isolated pool of connections.

Comment: That's why if your app makes a call to create_engine for every session, you end up having too many engines, each allocating a pool of connections but not using them.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same problem. but when i set `preload_app=False` in gunicorn file , then it gets fixed.